# Listar componente não visuais

Tags: c#, winforms

Já tentei vários meios para listar todos os componentes não visuais de um formulário, como: `OpenDialog`, `ImageList`, `TableAdapters` e etc. mas sem sucesso.

Para encontrar os controles na tela, eu consegui com um `Foreach` nos *Controls* da tela, mas para esses componentes não visuais, não achei nada.

Meu código atual:

```
private IEnumerable<Component> EnumerateComponents()
{
    return from field in GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
           where typeof (Component).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType)
           let component = (Component) field.GetValue(this)
           where component != null
           select component;
}
```

Alguma idéia de como fazer esse processo de listagem de componentes não visuais?

Comment: Você conseguiu isto nessa resposta, certo? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171914/find-components-on-a-windows-form-c-sharp-not-controls Ela não funciona? Acabo de ver que você postou no SOen também: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026373/find-components-non-visual-c-sharp Se achar uma resposta boa lá, posta aqui pra gente.

Comment: Com certeza @bigown. Encontrando uma resposta, eu posto por aqui.

Comment: @danielvillage acabei de realizar um teste com o código que você postou, aqui apareceu o ImageList e o OpenFileDialog que coloquei para testar.

Comment: @MateusAlexandre, esse código aqui é mais completo. É o que eu queria. Dê uma olhada:

return this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
           .Where(f => typeof(Component).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType))
           .Where(f => !typeof(Control).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType))
           .Select(f => f.GetValue(this))
           .OfType<Component>();

Answer (score 1):

Conforme foi postado nos comentários pelo próprio autor, o código abaixo lista todos os componentes não visuais de um formulário.

```
private IEnumerable<Component> EnumerateComponents()
{
    return this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Where(f => typeof(Component).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType))
            .Where(f => !typeof(Control).IsAssignableFrom(f.FieldType))
            .Select(f => f.GetValue(this))
            .OfType<Component>();
}
```

Originalmente em [Find Components Non Visual C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026373/find-components-non-visual-c-sharp).